# show dialog on fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialog

I have to show a dialog in a Fragment.
DialogFragment's code is:

```
public class DialogSintesi extends DialogFragment {

private TextView brownModelli;
private TextView brownArticoli;
private TextView blankModelli;
private TextView blankArticoli;
private TextView pedModelli;
private TextView pedArticoli;

public DialogSintesi() {

}

public static DialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
    DialogFragment fragment = new DialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override    
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_campagne_salvate, container);

    TextView brownModelli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBrownModelliNumero);
    TextView brownArticoli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBrownArticoliNumero);
    TextView blankModelli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBlankModelliNumero);
    TextView blankArticoli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBlankArticoliNumero);
    TextView pedModelli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPedModelliNumero);
    TextView pedArticoli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPedArticoliNumero);

    getDialog().setTitle("Sintesi Campagna");

    return view;
}
```

}

I try to show the dialog into a custom array adapter (pressing a button in a listview)

```
info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            showDialogSintesi();
        }

    });
```

And the method showDialogSintesi is:

```
public void showDialogSintesi(String nome) {
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = fragment.getFragmentManager();
    DialogFragment dialog = DialogSintesi.newInstance("Info");
    dialog.show(fm,"");

}
```

I try to show this dialog but it's many hours that it not work!
Sorry for my english.
Tha

Comment: Where are you declaring you `info` component?

Comment: What is the issue? It doesn't compile or the dialog doesn't appear?  Your method `showDialogSintesi` is supposed to take a string but you never pass anything to it in the `OnClickListener` registered to your `info` object

Comment: Yes, i have declare the image view info. Sorry but the method showDialogSintesi not supposed to take a string(is a method without parameters). It doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are using 
android.support.v4.app or android.app consistently across your code in import and declaring fragment related variables.

Comment: i had use android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment. I try to change libs but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing onCreateView with onCreateDialog:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    View view = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
            R.layout.popup_campagne_salvate, container);

    TextView brownModelli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBrownModelliNumero);
    TextView brownArticoli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBrownArticoliNumero);
    TextView blankModelli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBlankModelliNumero);
    TextView blankArticoli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBlankArticoliNumero);
    TextView pedModelli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPedModelliNumero);
    TextView pedArticoli = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPedArticoliNumero);

    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setTitle("Sintesi Campagna");

    Dialog dlg = builder.create();
    return dlg;
}
```

The rest should be as you did.
You can fill TextViews in this procedure.

Comment: The problem it's also in showDialogSintesi, because it doesn't compile. There's a problem on the line: dialog.show(fm,"")

Comment: sorry but i don't have the container if i use onCreateDialog

Comment: What do you mean you don't have a container?